# Put some resized images into directory and then specify it to train the images

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I have five RGB jpg images. I should to put all these image (converted to grayscale and resized to 160x160) into a directory whose take a place in my work file.

**1)** I read all the five RGB images :

```
img1 = imread('image1.jpg');
img2 = imread('image2.jpg');
img3 = imread('image3.jpg');
img4 = imread('image4.jpg');
img5 = imread('image5.jpg');
```

**2)** I convert their to **grayscale**:

```
img1_gray = rgb2gray(img1);
img2_gray = rgb2gray(img2);
img3_gray = rgb2gray(img3);
img4_gray = rgb2gray(img4);
img5_gray = rgb2gray(img5);
```

**3)** I resized all the images to **160x160**

```
img1_gray_resized=imresize(img1_gray, [160 160]);
img2_gray_resized=imresize(img2_gray, [160 160]);
img3_gray_resized=imresize(img3_gray, [160 160]);
img4_gray_resized=imresize(img4_gray, [160 160]);
img5_gray_resized=imresize(img5_gray, [160 160]);
```

**4)** i have a directory whose name is 'My_directory', and i need to put all my resized images into it. I used the `imwrite` function as shown just below, but i get an error and i think that it is completely not correct, that is why i need your help in this case.

```
imwrite(img1_gray_resized, 'My_directory','jpg');
imwrite(img2_gray_resized, 'My_directory','jpg');
imwrite(img3_gray_resized, 'My_directory','jpg');
imwrite(img4_gray_resized, 'My_directory','jpg');
imwrite(img5_gray_resized, 'My_directory','jpg');
```

**5)** In matlab, i need now to specify my directory for training all the images. I used the code below:

```
Train_images = 'My_directory';
```

It is not correct. Please how can i specify correctly my directory to train all my images into it ?

Any help will be very very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have another look at the syntax for [`imwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html).  The second argument needs to specify the file name, so you would need to specify the sub-directory and the file name together:

```
Train_images = 'My_directory';
mkdir(Train_images);
imwrite(img1_gray_resized, fullfile(Train_images,'image1_gray_resized.jpg'));
% and similarly on for the other 4 images
```

Also note that `imwrite` infers the format from the file extension.

Side note: If you care about image content, don't use jpg. Use png or bmp or something lossless.

Comment: Firstly, I would like to thank you for your answer, I appreciate it so much. But Look, first my directory is empty, i should to put my resized images into it in order to obtain a directory which contains 5 images. Does your code performs that ? By the way, i test your code and i get the following error : can't open file "My_directory\img1_gray_resized.jpg" for writing. You may not have write permission. So please can you help me ? thank's in advance! And sure i will change the format in order to have less compression

Comment: You'll need to first create the subdirectory.  Answer updated.

Comment: Ah yes, it works now, the directory is created in matlab folder not in work folder. Thank you very much dear chappjc :):):)